# osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=META-INF.cxf)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))

Tags: cxf, pom.xml, jbossfuse

I have generated this project with maven

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.servicemix.tooling
-DarchetypeArtifactId=servicemix-cxf-code-first-osgi-bundle
-DarchetypeVersion=2012.01.0.redhat-60024
-DgroupId=org.fusesource.example
-DartifactId=cxf-basic
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

created the boundle and trying to install and start it to Jboss Fuse I getting the Error

```
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
Unable to start bundle mvn:org.fusesource.example/cxf-basic/1.0-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle cxf-basic [363]: Unable to resolve 363.0: missing requirement [363.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=META-INF.cxf)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

I have already tried to change the version of

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>
                        javax.jws,
                        javax.wsdl,
                        javax.xml.bind,
                        javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                        javax.xml.namespace,
                        javax.xml.ws,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus.spring,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus.resource,
                        org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring,
                        org.apache.cxf.resource,
                        org.apache.cxf.jaxws,
                        org.apache.cxf.transport.http,
                        org.springframework.beans.factory.config
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Private-Package>
                        !org.fusesource.example.client,
                        org.fusesource.example,
                        org.fusesource.example.types
                    </Private-Package>
                    <Require-Bundle>org.apache.cxf.bundle</Require-Bundle>
                    <!--
                        <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    -->
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

with a new one but when I do it the error change slightly in

```
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
Unable to start bundle mvn:org.fusesource.example/cxf-basic/1.0-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle cxf-basic [362]: Unable to resolve 362.0: missing requirement [362.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jws)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of JBoss Fuse are you using? Why such and old archetype for your project?

Comment: At the moment I'm using the Jboss 6.3.0 and I'm using this archetype as a tutorial example to understand how Jboss fuse it works

Answer (score 0):

The package javax.jws is missing. You have to install the lib in your container with the good version (2.0.0).
If it is already the case, and you want to use the version provided, try this:

```
                    <Import-Package>
                        javax.jws;version="[1.0.0, 0)",
                        javax.wsdl,
                        javax.xml.bind,
                        javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                        javax.xml.namespace,
                        javax.xml.ws,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus.spring,
                        org.apache.cxf.bus.resource,
                        org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring,
                        org.apache.cxf.resource,
                        org.apache.cxf.jaxws,
                        org.apache.cxf.transport.http,
                        org.springframework.beans.factory.config
                    </Import-Package>
```